# Style table's cells without styling cells of children tables

Tags: css, css-selectors

Given this code, how do I implement a style such that only table "a" cells get padded, and not table "a" and table "b"?

```
<html>
  <style type="text/css">
  table.a td {background-color:green;} 
  table.b td {background-color:red;} 
  table {width:100%;}
  table.a tr td {padding:16px;} /*styles cells of table a and b*/
  </style>
</html>
<body>
 <table class="a">
  <tr>
   <td>&nbsp;</td>
   <td>
    <table class="b">
     <tr>
      <td>foo</td>
      <td>foo2</td>
     </tr>
    </table>     
   </td>
  </tr>
 </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the child selector ([spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#child-selectors)):

```
table.a > tbody > tr > td { padding:16px; }
```

Browsers seem to insert the 'missing' `tbody` element, so `table.a > tr > td` wont work.

Comment: There is no `tbody` element in that table.

Comment: In my Firefox it doesn't work without `tbody` although there is no `tbody` in the HTML code.

Comment: Wow, you're right. Firebug tells me it's inserting a `tbody`. I also just checked, Google Chrome and Opera both do the same, and IE does it if it's in standards mode. You may want to edit your answer to elaborate on this in case my comment is missed.

Comment: Adding tbody in the style doesn't work in IE, but without it, it doesn't work in Firefox.  I was using Firefox and omitting the tbody in the style which is why I wasn't able to get it to work.  I'll have to explicitly add the tbody to the markup to make it cross-browser compatible.

Answer (score 0):

Try using immediate child selector `table.a > tr{"my styles"}`